# Keras TPU. Compilation failure: Detected unsupported operations

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, google-cloud-tpu

I try to run my keras UNet model using Google Colab TPU and I faced this problem with `UpSampling2D`. Any solutions or workaround?

Code to run:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import UpSampling2D

model = Sequential()
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2), input_shape=(16, 16, 1)))
model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01), 
              loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

TPU_WORKER = 'grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR']
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)


model = tf.contrib.tpu.keras_to_tpu_model(
    model,strategy=tf.contrib.tpu.TPUDistributionStrategy(
        tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(TPU_WORKER)))

X = np.zeros((1024, 16, 16, 1))
Y = np.zeros((1024, 32, 32, 1))

model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=1024)
```

Error:

> RuntimeError: Compilation failed: Compilation failure: Detected
>   unsupported operations when trying to compile graph
>   cluster_3_5095732716396540171[] on XLA_TPU_JIT: ResizeNearestNeighbor
>   (No registered 'ResizeNearestNeighbor' OpKernel for XLA_TPU_JIT
>   devices compatible with node {{node
>   tpu_140211339657168/up_sampling2d_1/ResizeNearestNeighbor}} =
>   ResizeNearestNeighbor[T=DT_FLOAT, align_corners=false,
>   _device="/device:TPU_REPLICATED_CORE"](infeed-train_1:1, tpu_140211339657168/up_sampling2d_1/mul)
>         .  Registered:  device='CPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]
>         device='CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
>         device='CPU'; T in [DT_BFLOAT16]
>         device='CPU'; T in [DT_HALF]
>         device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT8]
>         device='CPU'; T in [DT_UINT8]
>         device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT16]
>         device='CPU'; T in [DT_UINT16]
>         device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT32]
>         device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT64]
>       ){{node tpu_140211339657168/up_sampling2d_1/ResizeNearestNeighbor}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error it looks like one of the operations in your Tensorflow backend (`ResizeNearestNeighbor`) graph for Keras is currently not compatible with TPUs. There are a small number of Tensorflow ops that are currently not available for TPUs ([Cloud TPU FAQs](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/faq)).

You can check out the current list of TPU compatible Tensorflow ops [here](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tensorflow-ops). You can also use Tensorboard to see [TPU Compatibility Graphs](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/cloud-tpu-tools#graphs).

As a workaround, you can try combine the TPU compatible Tensorflow ops to replicate the behavior of `ResizeNearestNeighbor`. In particular, you may be interested in the [ResizeBilinear](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/ops/resize-bilinear) Op, which is TPU compatible.