# Where can I identify which Keras methods are TPU compatible methods?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, google-cloud-tpu

I recently learned that UpSampling2D is not a TPU supported operation.

How do I find out which Keras functions are compatible with a TPU in Colab? I was unable to find any documentation on the subject.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keras TPU. Compilation failure: Detected unsupported operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52906186/keras-tpu-compilation-failure-detected-unsupported-operations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally all Keras layers should be supported, but there is not a nice summary. There is a more general summary that is related to TPU Ops [here](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tensorflow-ops).

In particular, UpSampling2D is a work in progress at this time, but you should be encouraged to file issues [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu) if you are having more problems with Keras and TPUs.